# Tangency Point in polynomial function

Tags: analytic-geometry

Sorry for my English

Can someone please help me? Taken from Lehmann's book. Group 45, exercise 6.
"If a polynomial function $f(x)$, when equal to $0$, has real roots with and even power , each equal to '$a$' ,( like $f(x)= (x+2)(x-1)^2 \to  a = 1$) , show that the curve $y=f(x)$ is tangent to the $X$ axis in the point $(a,0)$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description justifies that the polynomial function $f(x)$ should have the following form:
$$f(x)=p(x)(x-a)^{2k}, \,k\in \mathbb N^*,$$
where $p(x)$ is some other polynomial function. Then it is easy to see that 
$$f'(x)=p'(x)(x-a)^{2k}+2kp(x)(x-a)^{2k-1}.$$
Since $2k\ge 2$, it follows that $f'(a)=0$, and so the tangent line of the graph of $f(x)$ at $(a,0)$ is simply
$$y-0=0(x-a),$$
namely, 
$$y=0.$$
and so the horizontal axis and the graph of $f(x)$ are tangent to each other at $(a,0)$.

**A solution without using calculus**

Still we have
$$f(x)=p(x)(x-a)^{2k},\,\,k\in\mathbb N^*,$$
where we have further that $p(x)$ does not have the factor $x-a$, and so $p(a)\ne 0$. Without loss of generality, assume that $p(a)>0$. Since $p(x)$ is continuous, there must be some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $p(x)> 0$ on $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$. Thus, we have $f(a)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ on $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)\backslash \{a\}$. This also justifies the tangency.

Comment: Thanks! But , since this is in Lehmann's book, I was looking for a solution that didn't use calculus. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @user716981 A solution without using calculus (derivative and etc..) is attached, but a property of continuity is used.

Comment: Thanks for you help!